# Command to refresh environmental variables

Tags: windows, environment-variables

This question is w.r.t this [Is there a command to refresh environment variables from the command prompt in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171588/is-there-a-command-to-refresh-environment-variables-from-the-command-prompt-in) where you had posted a comment in which we could avoid using the batch file. It would really help if you can show the complete example. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

See on [Win32 api group](http://news://nntp.aioe.org/fr.comp.os.ms-windows.programmation)

for the official method (MS) to refresh environment variables