# How can I get the current user for App.config?

Tags: vb.net, app-config

I would like to get the current user for use in an app.config file. I can't just use `Environment.UserName` like I can in the VB file. Essentially I'm trying to have the app email whichever user is logged in rather than hard-coding a specific user.

Something that would work like this...

```
<add key="EmailFrom" value=Environment.UserName />
```

Note: the "Environment.UserName" is the correct effect I would like to get.

Comment: More info is needed, what is System.UserID?  What type of authentication is this?

Comment: It was just an example of how I would like to use the "user ID" in the config file.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Are you just trying to load a value from config?  Or dynamically update the config from some value discovered at runtime?

Comment: I would like to be able to put a value for the key that is not hard-coded but rather is based on the current user.

Comment: The config is meant for hardcoded values. You have the code to do any dynamic value. Why can't you do it in the code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set app.config value to Environment.UserName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313173/set-app-config-value-to-environment-username)