# Can I use an appSettings key's value within the same web.config file

Tags: .net, web-config

In my web.config I am setting the following key

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="myPath" value="//mypath.com" />
</appSettings>
```

Later in my web.config file I would like to use this value. Is this possible?

For example I would like to use it in a redirect rewrite map that I define later similar to this:

```
<rewriteMap name="myRewriteMap" defaultValue="">
    <add key="live" value="{Here I want to use the key 'myPath'}"/>
    <add key="dev2" value="http://mydevpath.com"/>
</rewriteMap>
```

Comment: did you have a look at the existing SO answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047181/is-it-possible-to-reuse-keys-in-web-config
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603009/variables-within-app-config-web-config?lq=1

Comment: @droidbot I never found it during my search. Doesn't seem to be exactly the same question but the proposed duplicate of that question is a duplicate of mine. Apparently it can't really be done...