# In vbscript, how do I run a batch file or command, with the environment of the current cmd prompt window?

Tags: command-line, vbscript, batch-file, cmd, environment-variables

In vbscript, how do I run a batch file or command, in the current cmd prompt window,

without starting a new process.

For example. According to script56.chm  (the vbscript help apparently) 
Windows Script Host
Run Method (Windows Script Host)
"Runs a program in a new process"

So if I have code that uses that e.g. a VBS file, and a BAT file.
An environment variable g has the value abc    g=abc
from that command window,
The VBS file calls the BAT file with windows scripting host Run. 
The bat process sets g=z.  and finishes.. and the vbs process finishes.
The environment variable is left untouched as g=abc.

I know
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "c:\test.bat", 0
starts a new window  as is clear when using 1 instead of 0. (since 0 hides the window)

How do I 
-run the bat file from the vbs, in the same cmd environment that the vbs was called in, so changes affect the cmd environment it was called in?
-In the two windows case which this one is at the moment, how do I access the environment of the parent cmd window, from the batch file?

Comment: This question is also asked at [How to set environment variables in vbs that can be read in calling batch script](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3737725/37941)

Comment: that's good, it's a similar question with relevant info.

Comment: The easiest solution here is not to mix technologies.  Ditch the batch file and do all of the work in the VBScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how do I run a batch file or command, in the current cmd prompt window, without starting a new process?

I don't think you can; your vbscript runs under a script host engine (such as `cscript.exe` or `wscript.exe`), and batch files are interpreted by the command interpreter (typically `cmd.exe`). Both are separate executables and neither is, to my knowledge, available as an in-process library, so you cannot interpret .vbs and .cmd files within the same process. I also highly doubt that the script host engine that is running your VBScript also could run the batch file in its parent cmd.exe - I don't think you can 'inject' a new batch file into a running cmd.exe.

> how do I access the environment of the parent cmd window, from the batch file?

Not just access, but change - [MSDN's "Changing Environment Variables"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682009%28VS.85%29.aspx) is quite explicit on this: **"Altering the environment variables of a child process during process creation is the only way one process can directly change the environment variables of another process. A process can never directly change the environment variables of another process that is not a child of that process."** You are trying to change the environment of the *parent*, not child, process. (I do wonder what 'directly' means in the context of this quote, though).

I would guess that the reason for this is security; imagine the havoc that could be wreaked if arbitrary processes could (maliciously or accidentally) change the PATH (or COMSPEC) environment variable of a running process, such as your vbscript host engine process - it could fail to launch your bat file entirely, breaking your program.

It would seem that you're out of luck - however, there are lots of other mechanisms for passing information between processes. Here are a couple of suggestions that are fairly simple to implement when talking between a batch file & vbscript, although it's by no means exhaustive:

- Exit codes
- Writing to & Parsing the consoleoutput (stdout) or a temp file

If you absolutely *need* to set environment variables in the parent cmd.exe (and also absolutely *need* the intermediate step of a vbscript), then you may have to write a wrapper batch file which runs the vbscript, consumes information produced by it and then sets environment variables; because the wrapper cmd is executing  *in* the top-level cmd process, it will be able to change the env vars there.

Footnote: Note that you *can* change the permanent system/user environment variables (as opposed to process environment variables) from within a VBScript, but I wouldn't recommend this if you are trying to create a transient state; besides this won't affect already-running processes (like the parent cmd.exe) anyway.

Comment: [This solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737725/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-vbs-that-can-be-read-in-calling-batch-script/3737791#3737791) gives an example of how to write the suggested wrapper batch file.

Comment: I would add.. since it's a cmd window calling a vbs calling a bat(which runs in its own cmd window).. it's more a question of a child process and grandparent process communicating or setting each other's environment variables ;-) but I see.. looks like not possible. interesting to see the different approach though in that question/"solution" you link to.