# Can I create Environmental variable which will take effect without logoff

Tags: environment-variables, registry

I am creating an Envoirment var using a bat file and the command is below:

```
REG ADD HKCU\Environment /v DSPATH /t REG_SZ /d %cd%\DSClient.exe
```

This works fine but only after a logoff. Is there a way it can take effect without logging off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Setx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755104%28WS.10%29.aspx) command to modify environment variables in the user or system environment, without requiring programming or scripting.

Programmatically, to effect these changes without having to log off, broadcast a `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message to all windows in the system, so that any interested applications (such as Windows Explorer, Program Manager, Task Manager, Control Panel, and so forth) can perform an update.

See:

- [How to propagate environment variables to the system](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/104011)
- [Refreshing environment variables from the command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171588/is-there-a-command-to-refresh-environment-variables-from-the-command-prompt-in-wi)