# Node not recognized although successfully installed

Tags: windows, node.js, path

I try to run *nodejs* on a brand new installation of *Windows 7*.
This is what I've done:

1. Install node using the windows installer
2. Make sure the files were extracted to `C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\`
3. Make sure that my Path enviorment variable contains `C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\`
4. open up a command prompt and run `node -v`

This gives me the `'node is not a recognized ...'` - message.

*What am I missing here?*

---

**Update**
running `echo %path%` gives me a directory listing that doesn't include `C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\`, even though looking at the "environment variables" tab in the system properties displays it under path. Thats odd.

Comment: Do you really think your laptop model matters? :p

Comment: What's the full path to the binary? Is it in ...\nodejs\, or ...\nodejs\bin\, for example?

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Hehe, no, not really. But when I have this kind of error that I really dont have a clue of the reason, I just try to include as much data as possible. The laptopmodel was probably just unnessesary though.

Comment: @jimw: I dont even have a nodejs\bin. In the nodejs dir, I have just a node application file.

Comment: Right, not that then. What does 'echo %PATH%' give you in your command shell? Sorry for the obvious questions :-)

Comment: @jimw Updated the question right before I saw this comment. Echoing path doesnt list the directory, still wondering how it could be visible under system properties then.

Comment: Aha! So for some reason you command shell isn't getting the environment variable from the GUI. A workaround would be to 'set PATH ...' in your command shell, but that doesn't solve the actual problem...

Comment: Solved it. Thanks for the help though @jimw :)

Comment: Ah good, glad to see you worked it out. Happy noding!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bash: npm: command not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45585029/bash-npm-command-not-found)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

UPDATE: a quicker solution is per Timos comment: "Restarting explorer.exe is enough, you can stop it in task manager and start it again"

This was solved by restarting the computer.

Apparently, using the Node installer sets the path so that it is visible under system properties, but not in the command prompt (running echo %path%) until you restart your computer. Not sure if this is a problem with Windows, or the Node Installer.

Comment: Changes to the System Properties will not affect any _open_ command prompts. You can simply re-open a new command prompt for the new PATH to take effect. Or manually add it in your %PATH% for existing command prompt.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure since this was a while ago, but I believe i did re-open the command prompt.

Comment: I can confirm the behaviour Soroush found. I didn't have any command prompts open, but the path wasn't picking up node after an install.

Comment: Restarting explorer.exe is enough, you can stop it in task manager and start it again

Comment: Another confirmation. I thought closing and reopening the command prompt window would enable it, but it didn't. Restarting explorer did it though without a restart.

Answer (score 15):

*Timo*'s statement is accurate. For completeness...

To start `explore.exe` again, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to open `Task Manager`

Then do  File > New Task (Run)> type: `explorer.exe` > Enter > Voila!

Comment: I guess as a developer, I already knew this? He did say restart explorer so I'm not sure how it is inaccurate.

Comment: I said it was accurate - I was simply helping by providing the steps to accomplish it. I would've added it in a comment, but don't have the required rep to do so.

Comment: To extend @sesamechicken and @Timo 's correct comments to the CLI; this can be done via a single line in `cmd`.  `taskkill /f /im explorer.exe && explorer.exe`.  This will kill the explorer.exe process and restart it.

Comment: Can you believe this issue is still happening? Restarting from the task manager using the menu option in Windows 10 doesn't work, at least for me. You must start explorer.exe again.

Comment: @S3DEV This worked for me but only after the desired new `PATH` was updated in same `cmd`.

Answer (score 1):

If node is installed via **nvm**.

Then it's important to run the command `nvm use <installed version>`.

And, it will hopefully work after that.