# Azure Compute Emulator UI not displaying due to error

Tags: azure, azure-compute-emulator

I'm getting an error when I try to view the Azure Compute Emulator UI.

Steps:

1. Launch an Azure project to kick off the emulator.
2. Right click on Azure emulator icon and select "Show Compute Emulator UI"

This produces the error:

> "This application has encountered an internal error and needs to be closed"

This has been working before but I haven't changed anything so does anyone know what could have started causing the error now? The Storage Emulator UI still seems to display OK.

I have the following environment:

- Windows 8.0
- Visual Studio 2012 Professional
- Azure SDK 2.2

Answer (score 0):

Create system variable and user variable in your system environment variables :_CSRUN_STATE_DIRECTORY with value like 'C:\TempAzure' (without commas). DO NOT LEAVE A SLASH AT THE END like 'C:\TempAzure\'.

Follow this link and do it and refresh your environment vars because compute emulator will not get them until refreshed.

[Is there a command to refresh environment variables from the command prompt in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171588/is-there-a-command-to-refresh-environment-variables-from-the-command-prompt-in-w)

This was the solution which worked for me.

A hint how I got it : 
 1. Start your event viewer and your azure sdk command prompt with elevated privileges ( as administrator )
 2. type csrun /devfabric:start
 3. Go to event viewer and hit F5 and look for the error from DFService.exe. There should be 2-3 new errors and the first should be from DFService. Look at the description - it should contain something like :

```
Application: DFService.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.ArgumentException
Stack:
   at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(System.String, Boolean)
   at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(System.String, Boolean, Int32, Boolean)
   at System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(System.String)
   at Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.DevelopmentFabric.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

The last row flashes the red lamp :)

Comment: I've tried the steps but I don't seem to get any errors appearing in the event viewer or the log files in C:\TempAzure. Maybe the Azure Compute Emulator UI sends error logs to a different place?

Comment: Be aware of the fact that if you start Event Viewer without Administrative privileges you will probably see the event log empty - right-click the event viewer icon and run as administrator. 
Every error is recorded in the event viewer under Application. And wait a bit if your log is big because it may take some time to parse and display it. Windows Azure Emulator error logs are under Windows Logs -> Application when you open Event Viewer.