# Get time in microsecond in delphi language

Tags: delphi

I work on delphi language and I need to compute time for process in microsecond.

I can compute time in hour minute second and millisecond, is there any function for compute time in microsecond in delphi language??

Comment: What do you mean by "get time" and "compute time". Please can you be precise.

Comment: RDTSC can give you most precise value you can achieve. Maybe look this way? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter

Comment: microsecond and millisecond are two entirely different scales of time.

Comment: @JerryDodge Hence the question

Comment: @David Yes, and I hate it when people delete their comments making mine look bad...

Comment: @Jerry, and I hate when people delete questions on whose people spend some time. Then they suddenly [`"come" up`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23482468/npm-failing-right-after-installing-node-js/23496004#comment36031364_23482468) with their own solution to a related question... Just deal with it ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a CPU-dependent "high resolution performance counter" that you can access with the `QueryPerformanceCounter()` API call.

`QueryPerformanceCounter()` gives you the value of that performance counter. (Historically, the performance counter was simply a count of CPU cycles, but hyper-threading and multi-core CPUs have made that unreliable, so now it just measures some very small interval of time, < 1us)

To find out what this unit of time is, use `QueryPerformanceFrequency()`. This gives you the number of high-resolution performance counter units per second. To get the number per microsecond, divide by 1000000. On my Sandy Bridge i7, it's about 35 units per microsecond.

Some code:

Using `QueryPerformanceCounter` to measure the execution time of some code:

```
var
  StartTime, EndTime, Delta: Int64;
begin
  QueryPerformanceCounter(StartTime);
  //Code you want to measure here
  QueryPerformanceCounter(EndTime);
  Delta := EndTime - StartTime;
  //Show Delta so you know the elapsed time
end;
```

Using `QueryPerformanceFrequency` to find out how many high-resolution units are in a microsecond:

```
var
  Frequency, UnitsPerMS: Int64;
begin
  QueryPerformanceFrequency(Frequency);
  UnitsPerMS := Frequency div 1000000;
end;
```

Comment: In Delphi you would use `TStopwatch` for a platform independent, OOP way to access high perf timers.

Comment: Yes, as long as you're using Delphi XE (I think) or newer. Since the question didn't specify which Delphi version is being used, I gave a more "universal" answer.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds to me like what you actually want to use is the [`TStopWatch`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Diagnostics.TStopwatch) type.  This provides a Delphi wrapper for `QueryPerformanceCounter()` and related APIs and hides all the details from you.  This is in the `System.Diagnostics` unit and is available from Delphi 2010.