# Switching between different JDK versions in Windows

Tags: java, windows, environment-variables

I'm working on few projects and some of them are using different JDK. Switching between JDK versions is not comfortable. So I was wondering if there is any easy way to change it?

I found 2 ways, which should solve this problem, but it doesn't work.

First solution is creating a bat files like this:

```
@echo off
echo Setting JAVA_HOME
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_72
echo setting PATH
set PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_72\bin;%PATH%
echo Display java version
java -version
pause
```

And after running this bat, I see right version of Java. But when I close this CMD and open a new one and type "java -version" it says that I still have 1.8.0_25. So it doesn't work.

Second solution which I found is an application from [this](http://mihosoft.eu/?p=649)  site. And it also doesn't work. The same effect as in the first solution.

Any ideas? Because changing JAVA_HOME and PAHT by: Win + Pause -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables -> and editing these variables, is terrible way...

Comment: Set path with batch file, and execute java too inside batch file.

Comment: As you can see both variables are setting in batch file. But I don't know how to execute java inside this file. I found this solution on another page and I don't know how to write batch files.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The `set` command only works for the current terminal. To permanently set a system or user environment variable you can use [`setx`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755104.aspx).

You can set the variable for the current user like this:

```
setx JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_72"
```

You can also set the variable system wide (Note: **The terminal must be run as administrator fo this**) by running the same command with the `/m` option:

```
setx JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_72" /m
```

The variable will be available in all new terminal session, but not the current one. If you also want to use the path in the same sessoin, you need to use both `set` and `setx`.

You can avoid manipulating the `PATH` variable if you just once put `%JAVA_HOME%` in there, instead of the full JDK path. If you change `JAVA_HOME`, `PATH` will be updated too.

---

There are also a few environment variable editors as alternative to the cumbersome Windows environment variable settings. See "[Is there a convenient way to edit PATH in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/297947/is-there-a-convenient-way-to-edit-path-in-windows-7)" on Super User.

Comment: Hmmm something is wrong... I did as you said and it adds these variables, but for user... And still when I open new terminal I get info that I have different JDK than I want...

Comment: It was missing the /m option, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Do I also have to replace the second "set" with "setx" (line: set PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_72\bin;%PATH%)?

Comment: @OddDev If you permanently want to change the PATH, you need to use `setx` there too. It will add the java path every time you run the script though, so it may be better to remove that line and to add `%JAVA_HOME%` to the PATH only once

Comment: Terminal or application needs a restart to take into account changes in `PATH` caused by updated `JAVA_HOME`. Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171588/is-there-a-command-to-refresh-environment-variables-from-the-command-prompt-in-w

Comment: ERROR: Access to the registry path is denied.

Comment: @ACV You'll get that error if you don't have permissions to set environment variables. You need to run `cmd` as administrator

Comment: @kapex yeah, which I can't. The solution for me was to use the `set` and run it every time in my console session before doing anything. Thanks

Answer (score 15):

In case if someone want to switch frequently in each new command window then I am using following approach.

**Command Prompt Version:**

Create batch file using below code. You can add n number of version using if and else blocks.

```
@echo off
if "%~1" == "11" (
   set "JAVA_HOME=C:\Software\openjdk-11+28_windows-x64_bin\jdk-11"
) else (
   set "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151"
)
set "Path=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%Path%"
java -version
```

Save this batch file as SJV.bat and add this file location in your machine's Path environment variable. So now SJV will act as command to "Switch Java Version".

Now open new command window and just type `SJV 11` it will switch to Java 11.
Type `SJV 8` it will switch to Java 8.

**PowerShell Version**

Create powershell(ps1) file using below code. You can add n number of version using if and else blocks.

```
If($args[0] -eq "11")
{
    $env:JAVA_HOME = 'C:\Software\openjdk-11+28_windows-x64_bin\jdk-11'
}else{
    $env:JAVA_HOME = 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151'
}
$env:Path = $env:JAVA_HOME+'\bin;'+$env:Path
java -version
```

Save this script file as SJV.ps1 and add this file location in your machine's Path environment variable. So now SJV will act as command to "Switch Java Version".

Now open new powershell window and just type `SJV 11` it will switch to Java 11.
Type `SJV 8` OR `SJV` it will switch to Java 8.

I hope this help someone who want to change it frequently.

Comment: Note to others: this works on the command line. But not powershell

Comment: @Jatin I have updated answer with PowerShell script also.

Comment: when I open other window and type "java -version", I get the old version

Comment: In each window you need to run SJV command first with required java version like SJV 8 or SJV 11. Then it will give proper version.

Answer (score 11):

1. Open `Environment Variables` editor (File Explorer > right click on
   This PC > Properties > Advanced system settings > Environment
   Variables...)
2. Find `Path` variable in *System variables* list >
   press Edit > put `%JAVA_HOME%bin;` at first position. This is required
   because Java installer adds `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
   Files\Oracle\Java\javapath` to the `PATH` which references to the latest Java version installed. [image]
3. Now you can switch between Java version using `setx` command (*should be run under administrative permissions*):

   ```
   setx /m JAVA_HOME "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\
   ```

   (note: **there is no double quote at the end of the line** and should not be or you'll get `c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\"` in your `JAVA_HOME` variable and it breaks your `PATH` variable)

Solution with system variables (and administrative permissions) is more robust because it puts desired path to Java at the start of the resulting `PATH` variable.

Comment: I tried this in Windows 10, it does not work, %JAVA_HOME%\bin is in path however java executable is not found

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the answer provided here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/64459399/894565).

I manually created environment variables via UI for `Java11`, `Java17` and `Java8`. To change across Java version:

From powershell (`PJV.ps1`):

```
if($args[0] -eq "11") {
   $Env:JAVA_HOME="$ENV:JAVA11"
   $Env:Path="$Env:JAVA_HOME\bin;$Env:Path"
} elseif($args[0] -eq "17") {
   $Env:JAVA_HOME="$ENV:JAVA17"
   $Env:Path="$Env:JAVA_HOME\bin;$Env:Path"
} elseif($args[0] -eq "8") {
   $Env:JAVA_HOME="$ENV:JAVA8"
   $Env:Path="$Env:JAVA_HOME\bin;$Env:Path"
}
set "Path=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%Path%"
java -version
```

From command line (`JV.bat`):

```
@echo off
if "%~1" == "11" (
   set "JAVA_HOME=%JAVA11%"
   setx JAVA_HOME "%JAVA11%"
) else if "%~1" == "17" (
   set "JAVA_HOME=%JAVA17%"
   setx JAVA_HOME "%JAVA17%"
) else (
   set "JAVA_HOME=%JAVA8%"
   setx JAVA_HOME "%JAVA8%"
)
set "Path=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%Path%"
java -version
```

Finally both these files are in the same folder. And this folder path has been added to my system `PATH`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your path have less than 1024 characters can execute (Run as Administrator) this script:

```
@echo off 
set "JAVA5_FOLDER=C:\Java\jdk1.5.0_22"
set "JAVA6_FOLDER=C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_45"
set "JAVA7_FOLDER=C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_80"
set "JAVA8_FOLDER=C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_121"
set "JAVA9_FOLDER=C:\Java\jdk-10.0.1"
set "CLEAR_FOLDER=C:\xxxxxx"

(echo "%PATH%" & echo.) | findstr /O . | more +1 | (set /P RESULT= & call exit /B %%RESULT%%)
set /A STRLENGTH=%ERRORLEVEL%
echo path length = %STRLENGTH%
if %STRLENGTH% GTR 1024  goto byebye 

echo Old Path: %PATH%
echo =================== 
echo Choose new Java Version:
echo [5] JDK5
echo [6] JDK6 
echo [7] JDK7
echo [8] JDK8
echo [9] JDK10
echo [x] Exit

:choice 
SET /P C=[5,6,7,8,9,x]? 
for %%? in (5) do if /I "%C%"=="%%?" goto JDK_L5 
for %%? in (6) do if /I "%C%"=="%%?" goto JDK_L6
for %%? in (7) do if /I "%C%"=="%%?" goto JDK_L7 
for %%? in (8) do if /I "%C%"=="%%?" goto JDK_L8 
for %%? in (9) do if /I "%C%"=="%%?" goto JDK_L9
for %%? in (x) do if /I "%C%"=="%%?" goto byebye
goto choice 

@echo on
:JDK_L5  
set "NEW_PATH=%JAVA5_FOLDER%"
goto setPath

:JDK_L6  
@echo off 
set "NEW_PATH=%JAVA6_FOLDER%"
goto setPath

:JDK_L7  
@echo off 
set "NEW_PATH=%JAVA7_FOLDER%"
goto setPath

:JDK_L8  
@echo off 
set "NEW_PATH=%JAVA8_FOLDER%"
goto setPath

:JDK_L9  
@echo off 
set NEW_PATH = %JAVA9_FOLDER%

:setPath
Call Set "PATH=%%PATH:%JAVA5_FOLDER%=%CLEAR_FOLDER%%%"
Call Set "PATH=%%PATH:%JAVA6_FOLDER%=%CLEAR_FOLDER%%%"
Call Set "PATH=%%PATH:%JAVA7_FOLDER%=%CLEAR_FOLDER%%%"
Call Set "PATH=%%PATH:%JAVA8_FOLDER%=%CLEAR_FOLDER%%%"
Call Set "PATH=%%PATH:%JAVA9_FOLDER%=%CLEAR_FOLDER%%%"
rem echo Interim Path: %PATH%
Call Set "PATH=%%PATH:%CLEAR_FOLDER%=%NEW_PATH%%%" 

setx PATH "%PATH%" /M

call set "JAVA_HOME=%NEW_PATH%"
setx JAVA_HOME %JAVA_HOME% 

echo New Path: %PATH%
:byebye
echo
java -version
pause
```

If more than 1024, try to remove some unnecessary paths, or can modify this scripts with some inputs from https://superuser.com/questions/387619/overcoming-the-1024-character-limit-with-setx

Answer (score 1):

Load below mentioned PowerShell script at the start of the PowerShell.  or generate the file using `New-Item $profile -Type File -Force`
this will create a file here `C:\Users\{user_name}\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile`

Now copy-paste the content given below in this file to be loaded each time the PowerShell is started

Set all the java versions you need as separate variables.

1. Java_8_home-> Points to Java 8 Location in local
2. Java_11_home -> Points to Java 11 Location in local
3. Java_17_home -> Points to Java 17 Location in local
4. Java_Home-> This points to the java version you want to use

Run in power shell to update the version to 8 `update_java_version 8 $True`

To update execution policy to allow script to be loaded at start of the PowerShell use below command
`Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force`

`

```
function update_java_version($version, [bool] $everywhere)
{
    switch ($version)
    {
        8 {
            $java_value = (Get-Item Env:Java_8_home).value
            $Env:Java_Home = $java_value
            refresh-path
            break
        }
        11 {
            $java_value = (Get-Item Env:Java_11_home).value
            $Env:Java_Home = $java_value
            refresh-path
            break
        }
        17 {
            $java_value = (Get-Item Env:Java_17_home).value
            $Env:Java_Home = $java_value
            refresh-path
            break
        }
        default {
            throw "No matching java version found for `$version`: $version"
        }
    }
    if ($everywhere)
    {
        [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Java_Home", $java_value, "User")
    }
}

function refresh-path
{
    $env:Path = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "Machine") +
            ";" +
            [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "User")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this BAT file to conveniently change the java version.

### Pros:

1. It does NOT modify the PATH system environment variable.
2. The only thing that has to be maintained is the relational array (can be conveniently constructed as a sparse array) that holds the version number and the path at the beginning of the script.

### Precondition:

The following entry `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` has to be [appended](https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-on-windows-10/) to the `PATH` environment variable.

```
@echo off
@cls
@title Switch Java Version
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

:: This bat file Switches the Java Version using the JAVA_HOME variable.
:: This script does NOT modify the PATH system environment variable.
:: Precondition: The following entry "%JAVA_HOME%\bin" has to be appended to the PATH environment variable.
::  Script Name: SwitchJavaVersion | Version 1 | 2021/11/04

rem Add items to vector as follows:
rem   AvailableVersions["Java Major Version Number"]="Java Absolute Path"
set AvailableVersions[8]="D:\Program Files\Java\jdk8u252-b09"
set AvailableVersions[17]="D:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.1"

call :PrintJavaVersion
call :PrintAvailableVersions
call :GetJavaVersion
call :SetJavaVersion
call :ResetLocalPath
if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit /b %errorlevel%
call :PrintJavaVersion

pause
endlocal
exit /b


rem Print available versions.
:PrintAvailableVersions
    echo Available Java Versions:
    for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%I in ('set AvailableVersions[') do echo ^> %%I
    exit /b

rem Get version from user input or command-line arguments.
:GetJavaVersion
    set "JavaVersion="
    if "%~1"=="" (
        set /p JavaVersion="Type the major java version number you want to switch to: "
    ) else (
        set /a JavaVersion="%~1"
    )
    exit /b


rem Update JAVA_HOME user variable with hardcoded paths.
:SetJavaVersion
    set JavaPath=
    for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%I in ('set AvailableVersions[') do (
        if "%%I" == "%JavaVersion%" (
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            set JavaPath=!AvailableVersions[%%I]!
            setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
        )
    )

    if not defined JavaPath (
        echo "Specified version NOT found: Default settings applied."
        for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('set AvailableVersions[') do (
            set JavaPath=%%I
            goto exitForJavaPath
        )
        
    )
    :exitForJavaPath

    rem remove quotes from path
    set JavaPath=%JavaPath:"=%
    set "JAVA_HOME=%JavaPath%"
    setx JAVA_HOME "%JAVA_HOME%"
    
    rem setlocal statement was run 2 times previously inside the for loop; therefore, the endlocal statement must be executed 2 times to close those nested local scopes.

    
    rem below endlocal statement will close local scope set by previous "setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion" statement
    endlocal & set "JavaPath=%JavaPath%"
    rem JAVA_HOME's value rolls back due to endlocal statement so the appropriate value has to be reassigned
    set "JAVA_HOME=%JavaPath%"
    rem below endlocal statement will close local scope set by previous "setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion" statement
    endlocal & set "JavaPath=%JavaPath%"
    rem JAVA_HOME's value rolls back due to endlocal statement so the appropriate value has to be reassigned
    set "JAVA_HOME=%JavaPath%"
    
    exit /b


rem Get User and System Path variable's definition from Registry,
rem    evaluate the definitions with the new values and reset
rem    the local path variable so newly set java version
rem    is properly displayed.
:ResetLocalPath
    set "PathValue="
    for /F "skip=2 tokens=1,2,*" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe QUERY "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /V Path') do if /I "%%I" == "Path" if not "%%~K" == "" if "%%J" == "REG_SZ" (set "PathValue=%%~K") else if "%%J" == "REG_EXPAND_SZ" call set "PathValue=%%~K"

    if not defined PathValue goto pathError

    set "UserPathValue="
    for /F "skip=2 tokens=1,2,*" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe QUERY "HKCU\Environment" /V Path') do if /I "%%I" == "Path" if not "%%~K" == "" if "%%J" == "REG_SZ" (set "UserPathValue=%%~K") else if "%%J" == "REG_EXPAND_SZ" call set "UserPathValue=%%~K"

    if not defined UserPathValue goto pathError
    
    call set "Path=%PathValue%;%UserPathValue%"

    echo Path variable reset:
    echo PATH=%Path%  
    echo.
    exit /b


rem Display the Java version.
:PrintJavaVersion
    echo Current Java Version:
    java -version
    echo.
    exit /b


rem Error handling subroutine.
:pathError
    echo.
    echo Error while refreshing the PATH variable:
    echo PathValue=%PathValue%
    echo UserPathValue=%UserPathValue%
    pause
    exit /b 2

endlocal
exit
```