# Switching between different JDK versions in Windows PowerShell

Tags: java, windows, powershell

As suggested previously by @PrakashBoda (https://stackoverflow.com/a/64459399/894565).

I am trying to create a PowerShell script to switch between multiple versions of Java in my Windows machine. FYI I do not have Admin access to my Windows laptop as this is my work machine.

As suggested by @Prakash, I have modified the code to reflect my local jdk path locations.

```
If($args[0] -eq "11")
{
    $env:JAVA_HOME = 'C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-11.0.22.7-hotspot'
}else{
    $env:JAVA_HOME = 'C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-8.0.402.6-hotspot'
}

If($args[1] -eq "17")
{
    $env:JAVA_HOME = 'C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.10.7-hotspot'
}else{
    $env:JAVA_HOME = 'C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-8.0.402.6-hotspot'
}

If($args[2] -eq "21")
{
    $env:JAVA_HOME = 'C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-21.0.2.13-hotspot'
}else{
    $env:JAVA_HOME = 'C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-8.0.402.6-hotspot'
}
$env:Path = $env:JAVA_HOME+'\bin;'+$env:Path
java -version
```

I have saved the file as `jdk.ps1` at location `C:\JDKScripts` (Created a new JDKScipts Folder in C Drive).
I have given the Path of this Folder in System Variables > PATH. (Since I don't have Admin access, I asked my ServiceNow Help Desk Team to assist me in adding this in System Path Variables)

But when I open new PowerShell window and run the following commands `jdk 11` or `jdk 17` or `jdk 21` I am still getting the java 1.8.0 version

```
PS C:\Users\xxxxxx> jdk 11
openjdk version "1.8.0_402"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Temurin)(build 1.8.0_402-b06)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Temurin)(build 25.402-b06, mixed mode)
PS C:\Users\xxxxxx> jdk 17
openjdk version "1.8.0_402"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Temurin)(build 1.8.0_402-b06)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Temurin)(build 25.402-b06, mixed mode)
PS C:\Users\xxxxxx> jdk 21
openjdk version "1.8.0_402"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Temurin)(build 1.8.0_402-b06)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Temurin)(build 25.402-b06, mixed mode)
```

Does it needs any changes to the PATH variables in System settings?

What am I missing here? Please guide me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple errors in your script:

1. Using different indexes for `$args[]` but the argument is always at the same position in the command line: `$args[0]`
2. Using separate ifs that may overwrite the previous value. Instead use if/elseif/else.

I added that if the selected value is not a valid option to abort with an error. Feel to change that to use a default value instead.

```
If ($args[0] -eq "11") {
    $env:JAVA_HOME = 'C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-11.0.22.7-hotspot'
} Elseif ($args[0] -eq "17") {
    $env:JAVA_HOME = 'C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.10.7-hotspot'
} Elseif ($args[0] -eq "21") {
    $env:JAVA_HOME = 'C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-21.0.2.13-hotspot'
} Elseif ($args[0] -eq "8") {
    $env:JAVA_HOME = 'C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-8.0.402.6-hotspot'
} Else {
    Write-Output "Error: Unknown JDK $args[0]" 
    exit 1
}
$env:Path = $env:JAVA_HOME+'\bin;'+$env:Path
```