# using variables from VBScript in batch

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I want to pass variables from VBScript to batch but it wouldn't work.

My VBScript:

```vb
Dim shell  
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strnaam = InputBox ("naam")
```

and my batch:

```batch
@echo off
cls
echo %strnaam%
pause
```

I want the variable `strnaam` from my VBScript to my batch.

Comment: VBScript and batch are running in separate processes and thus cannot share internal variables. There might be ways to sort-of do what you want (e.g. using environment variables), but you need to provide more information about how the 2 scripts are related to each other and how they're being run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the variables only via environment variables:

1. The `create_variable.vbs` file:

```
Dim WshShell, WshEnv
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WshEnv = WshShell.Environment("USER") ' can be either SYSTEM, USER, VOLATILE OR PROCESS
' current value
WScript.Echo "Process: NAAM=" & WshEnv.Item("NAAM")
WshEnv("NAAM") = "This text will appear in batch"
WScript.Echo "Process: NAAM=" & WshEnv.Item("NAAM")
Set WshEnv = Nothing
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

2. Then the **batch** file `show_vbs_variable.bat` (you have to open a new cmd.exe to have the new variable there!  If you need more infor [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171588/is-there-a-command-to-refresh-environment-variables-from-the-command-prompt-in-w) is a topic on SO that covers it.:

```
@echo off
cls
echo %naam%
pause
```

3. **vbs** script for clearing up the variable `clearing_variable.vbs`:

```
Dim WshShell, WshEnv
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WshEnv = WshShell.Environment("USER") ' can be either SYSTEM, USER, VOLATILE OR PROCESS
' current value
WScript.Echo "Process: NAAM=" & WshEnv.Item("NAAM")
'Deleting the env variable
WshEnv.Remove("NAAM")
WScript.Echo "Process: NAAM=" & WshEnv.Item("NAAM")
Set WshEnv = Nothing
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Answer (score 3):

The most obvious way would be to run the [vbscript](/questions/tagged/vbscript) as a `For /F` command and save its returned output as a variable:

```bat
@Echo Off

:NaamBox
Set "naam="
(Echo WScript.Echo InputBox("Naam:"^))>"%TEMP%\naam.vbs"
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%A In ('CScript //NoLogo "%TEMP%\naam.vbs"')Do Set "naam=%%A"
If Not Defined naam GoTo NaamBox
Del "%TEMP%\naam.vbs"

Echo Uw naam is %naam%
Pause
```

If you don't like the idea of writing, running, then deleting the file, you could also embed your VBScript within the batch file:

```bat
<!-- :
@Echo Off
Echo Typ gelieve uw naam in de popup doos en OK te selecteren
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%A In ('CScript //NoLogo "%~f0?.wsf"')Do Set "naam=%%A"
If Defined naam Echo Uw naam is %naam%&Pause
Exit /B
-->
<Job><Script Language="VBScript">
    WScript.Echo InputBox("Naam:")
</Script></Job>
```