# Setting environment variables in a shell script for a React app

Tags: reactjs, powershell, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I am trying to set some environment variables in a powershell (and bash) script and read them in a ReactJS application. The shell script is simple:

```
$env:AUTHDOMAIN="some.domain.com"
$env:AUTHCLIENTID="bunch-o-characters"
$env:AUTHCALLBACK="http://somewhere:3002/callback"
$env:AUTHAUDIENCE="auth-audience"

$env:PORT=3002

# Get-ChildItem Env:

yarn start
```

The port is being picked up correctly by `yarn` but none of the variables (including `PORT`) are available via `process.env` within the React javascript.

```
console.log("domain     : " + process.env.AUTHDOMAIN);
...
domain     : undefined App.js:33
```

No mods to my `package.json` file:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

What am I missing? `Get-ChildItem` shows that the variables are set correctly in the environment.

Edit: I tried the solution listed [here](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables) and it doesn't work. It also blocks the terminal from receiving any output:

```
$ ($env:AUTHDOMAIN="some.domain.com") -and (yarn start)
```

Same result.

Edit #2: It's worth noting that the behavior is *exactly the same* in linux/bash (which is a good litmus test cuz I've done this in bash about a 100 billion times) - yarn sets the port correctly but none of the info makes it into the react app:

```
#!/bin/sh

export AUTHDOMAIN="some.domain.com"
export AUTHCLIENTID="bunch-o-text"
export AUTHCALLBACK="http://somewhere:3001/callback"
export AUTHAUDIENCE="auth-audience"

export PORT=3002

yarn start
```

So this likely has nothing to do with powershell.

Comment: Is this just an issue of context? If you set the variables in the system context instead of current user, do you get a different result?

Comment: Do you mean via `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable()`? I'd rather not do that. For the record I do this exact same thing to load env vars into the golang api and the api sees them just fine.

Comment: The env variables do in fact persist in the environment after I kill the server which is kind of vexing.

Comment: You need to reload the process shell to load the environment changes, see e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/q/171588/1701026

Comment: @iRon I don't think any of that applies. This is powershell not cmd.exe, the env vars are definitely getting set (as shown by Get-ChildItem) and this same setup works fine with a golang application that uses environment variables. I don't want the vars to be system wide, just local to the script process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every environment variable you wish to consume must be prefixed with `REACT_APP_`
as per the [documentation of create-react-app](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables):

> Note: You must create custom environment variables beginning with REACT_APP_. Any other variables except NODE_ENV will be ignored to avoid accidentally exposing a private key on the machine that could have the same name. Changing any environment variables will require you to restart the development server if it is running.

Comment: Just found that - thanks! It's worth noting that, as above, the env vars being sent to yarn (react-scripts) do NOT have this requirement.

Comment: The bit about restarting was useful! Thanks