# How do I pass arguments to react-scripts start command and use them in react?

Tags: environment-variables, yarnpkg, react-scripts

I have a .sh file with the follow code:

```
react-scripts start HOST=0.0.0.0
```

And my yarn start scripts is:

```
"scripts": {
"start": "./run.sh",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
```

},

The problem is that when I access to process.env object on a react component, I don't see this variable. How can I do this to work?

Comment: If you want to set an env var you need to do it _first_, that's just passing some unhandled arguments to react-scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seem to work for me: [Setting environment variables in a shell script for a React app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55666337/setting-environment-variables-in-a-shell-script-for-a-react-app)

So the solution is to add REACT_APP as prefix of your variables.

My .sh file ended like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
export REACT_APP_PYTHON_API_IP="localhost"
yarn start
```