# Refresh environment variables in Azure Pipeline build

Tags: cmd, environment-variables, yaml, azure-pipelines, teststand

How to I refresh environment variables for later steps in the same build that indirectly changes those variables?

Section of a the test YAML file that reproduces the described behavior.

```
jobs:
- job: welldone
  pool: 
    name: noodle
  steps:
  - script: |
      echo select TestStand 2016
      start /wait "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\National Instruments\Shared\TestStand Version Selector\TSVerSelect.exe" /version 16.0 /installing /noprompt
    displayName: 'select TestStand version 16'

  - script: |
      echo Check TestStand version
      echo %TestStand%
      call RefreshEnv.cmd
      echo %TestStand%
    displayName: 'print TestStand version'

  - script: |
      call checkTSversion.bat
      call RefreshEnv.cmd
      call checkTSversion.bat
    displayName: 'call bat file to print TestStand version'
```

First script calls [TestStand Version Selector](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/370052W-01/tsref/infotopics/versionselector/) that changes environment variables among other things.

2nd script prints environment variables starting with "teststand", then calls [refreshenv.cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32420542/2642280) and prints variables again. First prints old variables, second - updated. This is consistent with expected behavior of cmd, I suppose.

3rd script does the same, but now the `echo %TestStand%` is in a separate batch file. It behaves exactly as 2nd script.

What can I do in the 1st script to make sure that consecutive scripts will read updated environment variables?

Comment: You can't. Each time you start a new instance of cmd and change environment variables it does not pass those changes up to the parent cmd.

Comment: @DavidPostill thanks for your comment. It looks like it is the answer to my question (i.e. "nothing you can do, impossible"). I can update variables for the current script though. Is there a better way to do it? Entirely different approach, maybe? Should I ask another, differently phrased question then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure that I understand your sample pipeline, but it seems to me like you want to set variables and/or change variable values in a job step and then use the new value in a later job step. Correct? If so, you're looking for something like this:

```
steps:
# Create a variable
# Note that this does _not_ update the environment of the current script.
- bash: |
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=sauce]crushed tomatoes"

# An environment variable called `SAUCE` has been added to all downstream steps
- bash: |
    echo "my environment variable is $SAUCE"
- pwsh: |
    Write-Host "my environment variable is $env:SAUCE"
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts