# How do I start a Windows 7 console with a newly modified system environment?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, environment-variables, start-process

I have written a (very simple) little Python script, and I want to be able to distribute it to friends who have no idea what Python is, nor anything about Windows *cmd* scripts.

Fundamentally I need to install Python on their systems, followed by installing the required libraries for my script, followed by my script (and appropriate start-up links in their desktop).

I have no interest in creating some sophisticated install program.  Thus, I have written a very simple, trivial little *cmd* script to do the install (and created a self-extracting archive that runs the install script).

In the archive, I have the Internet-accessing install executables for installing Python.  The script tests for an existing Python install, and when none is found, it installs Python. This works well.

But, after installing Python, I need to install some required modules/libraries that do not come pre-bundled with Python.  It would be nice to be able to use [pip3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_%28package_manager%29) to install these libraries.  Fundamentally, this is what needs to be run:

```
python-3.8.2-webinstall.exe  PrependPath=1
pip3 install --user requests python-dateutil pychromecast gtts
```

The problem here is that after the Python web install, the process (console process) running this script *does not inherit the new settings (especially the new path settings) from the web install process*, and so the `pip3` command fails.

My first attempt to remedy this was to use the console START command to start the `pip3` command in a separate process that would have the new settings:

```
python-3.8.2-webinstall.exe  PrependPath=1
START "PythonRequireds" /I /wait cmd /C "pip3 install --user requests python-dateutil pychromecast gtts"
```

From the documentation for the [START](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) command, I would have expected the /I option would ensure the started process had a new environment including the changes from the just-completed web install.  Alas, it was not to be: the `pip3` command was still not found.

How can I start a new process from a Windows console script, so that the new process has all the changes to the path just placed in the registry by the install process?

Comment: Did you check out the related article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171588/is-there-a-command-to-refresh-environment-variables-from-the-command-prompt-in-w?rq=1 ?

Comment: Programs inherit the environment from their parent. Programs can, I have no idea if PIP3 does, change the system environment and send a message telling program to reread it. The only known program to do this is Windows Explorer (although sometime in the past I posted a program that tells you it happened). So your changes are lost.

Comment: how about [**not** installing phyton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-to-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependency)?

Comment: @Antares Thanks for this.  Charles Grunwald's answer there was exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Stephan A very attractive idea that would provide a superior solution to my "install" setup.  Unfortunately, my AV program (Avast), and I understand many others, flag the self-contained executables as having virus content.  Very unfortunate.

Comment: @Stephan Changed anti-virus software.  Avast/AVG flag .exe's generated by pyinstaller as virus, Kaspersky does not.

Comment: The new environment changes should not be needed if you look into the registry to [get the install path](http://users.tpg.com.au/mpheath/support/61473551.html). This does not relate to getting a new environment as your question asks so is not a related answer, though you could still reach your goal with running pip in the same code. If you want to copy the linked page, you may do so as a permanent record.

Comment: @michael_heath Thanks for this! Yes, I understand now why you deleted it. But you've saved me time tracking down the reg entries, so thanks, much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a command to refresh environment variables from the command prompt in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171588/is-there-a-command-to-refresh-environment-variables-from-the-command-prompt-in-w)

Comment: @SherylHohman: The first posted comment by Antares actually referenced the same post, and I responded above in the affermative.