# Batch File for installing python and running script

Tags: python, batch-file

I am writing utility which does the following things:

1. Check Python has installed it or not.
   if Not Installed, Script downloads the python and install it. In the same session, it executes the python script.

But I am facing one issue here, as soon as the script install python, it's throwing an error while executing the python script as python is not recognized in cmd. But if I run the same program again it works fine.

The problem here is - after installation of Python, the command prompt is not identifying the python command unless I restart the window.

is there any way?

Script is:
Getting error at below highlighted section

```
:errorNoPython

echo.
echo Error^: Python not installed
echo.
echo.
echo Downloading Python 3.7.0...
IF EXIST "%CD%\python-3.7.0.exe" (
  echo Found Installer at "%CD%\python-3.7.0.exe"
) ELSE (
  powershell -Command "& {[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12, [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls11, [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Ssl3, [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls; Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.0/python-3.7.0.exe' -OutFile '%CD%\python-3.7.0.exe';}"
  echo Python download completed.
)

echo Installing Python...
powershell %CD%\python-3.7.0.exe /quiet InstallAllUsers=0 PrependPath=1 Include_test=0 TargetDir=c:\Python\Python370
setx path "%PATH%;C:\Python\Python370\"

timeout /t 30 /nobreak > nul
echo Python Installation completed.
echo Installing python dependencies.
**start cmd /k python -m pip install requests
start cmd /k python -m pip install pyjavaproperties**
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a command to refresh environment variables from the command prompt in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171588/is-there-a-command-to-refresh-environment-variables-from-the-command-prompt-in-w)

Comment: Even after refreshing environment variables, i am getting below error - 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. But when I ran same command on command prompt one by one after refreshing environment via resetvers.vbs its working properly but via batch file its not working

Comment: No, Its not working at all.

Comment: One weird observation. If I run python command manually its working as expected but if i am calling python script via batch file its showin error   'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Answer (score 1):

In order to reload the environment, you have to close and open `cmd.exe`

So to get around it, you can `set` the path and `setx`

Copy exactly as is, but this will set the path in the current environment:

```
setx path "%PATH%;C:\Python\Python370\"
set "path=%PATH%;C:\Python\Python370\"
```

Comment: Yes, but in my case i am installing python and planning to run some python script. so i cant restart the command prompt.

Comment: Did you read everything? just copy the `set` line as is into your code, below the `setx` line as demonstrated.