# NLS_LANG issue for two Oracle Homes on the same host, not refreshing the System and User Environment

Tags: database, oracle, batch-file, character-encoding, nls-lang

I have **tow Oracle 6i - Patch 17 applications** running on the same host. Befoe they used to run on two different Windows installation for each one; but this is not conveniant.

Each application is developed by a different company.

I managed to install Oracle 6i client on Windows 11 64 bit.

Both applications work perfectly except when it comes to NLS_LANG variable.

The first application has its own server. **SERVER-1** and the second application has its own server **SERVER-2**.

The oracle database on **SERVER-1** USES `NLS_LANG=ARABIC_UNITED ARAB EMIRATES.AR8MSWIN1256`

The oracle database on **SERVER-2** USES `NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P1`

I created a batch file to set NLS_LANG for each Oracle Client application; and they user need to run the patch then run the application.

This is the Batch1.bat for Application1 for SERVER-1

```
NET STOP OracleClientCache80 'Stop Oracle service if runninig 
SETX NLS_LANG "ARABIC_UNITED ARAB EMIRATES.AR8MSWIN1256"
SETX NLS_LANG "ARABIC_UNITED ARAB EMIRATES.AR8MSWIN1256" -M
NET START OracleClientCache80 ' Start Oracle service to adapt NLS_LANG changes
```

This is the Batch2.bat for Application2 for SERVER-2

```
NET STOP OracleClientCache80
SETX NLS_LANG "AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P1"
SETX NLS_LANG "AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P1" -M
NET START OracleClientCache80
```

This what works perfectly but not what I really want:

I run Batch1.bat then log-off Windows and log-in again --> all perfect.
I run Batch2.bat then log-off Windows and log-in again --> all perfect.

**But if I didn't log-off/log-in I got weired charachters in the report preview while trying to print it.**

As attached:

[image: Strange Charset Encoding]

**If I *DID* log-out/log-in; I don't face any issue with charachter encoding and NLS_LANG.**

**Is there a way to force to refresh NLS_LANG added by the batch to Windows Variables and avoid log-off/log-in?**

*This is my main question and goal!*

I found many refrences for this but none of them worked out for me!

Some suggested to restart exploere.exe and others suggested using external library like [Chocolatey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44807922/18998774)

What would be the perfect senario please?

Thank you

Comment: `setx` sets the value of the variable for all **future** `cmd` instances, not for any instances that have already been established **including the current instance**. use `set "NLS_LANG=whateverstingisappropriate"`

Comment: @Magoo Thank you for your suggestion; but it didn't work...It gives ????? for reports preview for SERVER-2 and I am forced to log-out/log-in to make it work! Any idea please? Thanks alot

Comment: Perhaps you should use `/M` in place of `-M`. `/` is used for most switches in Windows; `-` is sometimes used for utilities ported from other systems.