# Python and pip installation during setup via batch file

Tags: python, batch-file, installation, pip, inno-setup

I'm currently setting up the installer for a tool I wrote, that utilizes another small python tool, which i need to install via pip.
I do this by running a batch-file during the setup.
(I use InnoSetup for my installer)

Now...the Python installation works no-problem, but afterwards the commandline still thinks that python is not installed and thus cannot interpret the "pip"-command.

I've already tried restarting the commandline, aswell as putting the pip-command in a different file alltogether, which gets called after the first one.
None of that had any positive results.

The only idea i have left is restarting the PC during the setup, but i'd really like to avoid that. (I'll try it after this post and let you know if it worked) Edit: I could actually not find a way to that.

So, if anyone has some input, how I could achieve that, i'll gladly try it.

Here is the (current) code of my batch file:

```
python --version 2>NUL
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 GOTO INSTOLE

ECHO.
ECHO oleidUI requires a valid Python-Installation
ECHO.
:INSTPY
SET /p answer=Do you want to run the Setup for Python v.3.10.7 now? Y / N 
IF /i %answer:~,1% EQU Y GOTO :PYSETUP
IF /i %answer:~,1% EQU N GOTO :NOPYTHO
ECHO [Y]es / [N]o
GOTO INSTPY

:PYSETUP
ECHO.
ECHO python-3.10.7-amd64.exe will start now
START /WAIT python-3.10.7-amd64.exe
START install.bat

:INSTOLE
pip install -U oletools[full]
IF %ERRORLEVEL% GTR 1 GOTO NOPYTHO
PAUSE
EXIT

:NOPYTHO
ECHO After installing Python please run [Installation Folder]\oleidUi\resources\app\Setup\install.bat to finalize the installation of oleidUI
PAUSE
EXIT
```

Answer (score -1):

Solution: I used this [Is there a command to refresh environment variables from the command prompt in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171588/is-there-a-command-to-refresh-environment-variables-from-the-command-prompt-in-w/32420542#32420542) and just put it before i call the pip command